# Improve Nginx Server Response Time

Tags: nginx, pagespeed, server-administration

I'm currently running an Ubuntu 12.04LTS with nginx handing out requests.

I ran my site through google page speed (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) and the main tip it had was to Improve server response time, but it doesn't give much detail into how to do this.

It mostly just listed off some webfonts I'm using (css @font-face) and a couple of images small png's and a gif.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also use Ubuntu 12.04LTS with nginx and ngx_pagespeed

You can follow this link to compile nginx with ngx_pagespeed:
https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed#how-to-build
You can increase your score without requiring to modify your code.

If you want to get a perfect PageSpeed score, this article might help you:
http://www.appneta.com/blog/bootstrap-pagespeed . 
https://github.com/danriti/bootstrap-pagespeed